# How to make a choice between PooledDataSource and dbcp when I work with the MyBatis?

Tags: java, datasource, mybatis, apache-commons-dbcp

I am now config a project work with spring and mybatis.

There are many example online tell me should use a `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` as the datasource, but mybatis use `PooledDataSource` as the datasource, it's confusing me. so, I read source codes of the `DirverManagerDataSource`, it's just a mock pool connection. so, I know how to make a choice.

But, I have a new problem soon. How to make a choice between `PooledDataSource` and `DBCP`? I read source codes of the `PooledDataSource`, it's also a simple implementation, but the codes of these two lib is too complex, i don't have enough time to read these codes.

can you tell me which is more powerful? and why? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Spring and MyBatis, it functionally does not matter what you use. As long as there is a `DataSource` available to the configuration, then everything will work. With Spring, it is usually easiest to create the `DataSource` in the Spring config and pass that to a MyBatis `SqlSessionFactoryBean`.

MyBatis' `PooledDataSource` should be ok from a performance perspective but it does `synchronize` so it *may* have contention issues as very high concurrency. It can be configured in Spring as a normal bean.

DPCP has more features (esp JMX monitoring) and version 2 should have better performance than DPCP v1.

If you are running in a container you may want to use the container's pool via JNDI (see `JndiObjectFactoryBean`). If you are using Tomcat, it will have it's own [pool implementation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html%20(pool%20implementation)).

Comment: If running in a container, usually use the container's pool via JNDI?

Comment: Are there any difference between container's pool and third-party pool when I running in a container?

Comment: example, the difference between Tomcat's pool and DPCP V2 when I am running in the Tomcat?

Comment: In a container, you would use JNDI. It will be easier to use Tomcat's pool. To use DPCP, you would need to create a custom `<Resource>` with the factory attribute set to `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory`.